# How can I filter netCDF variables with specific conditions in Python?

Tags: python, filter, boolean, conditional-statements, netcdf

I am reading in a netCDF file and want to keep data from other variables based on the filter condition (vwc < 5) where vwc is a variable.

My errors include AttributeError: NetCDF: Attribute not found and AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'where' since I tried using the where function but I could have been using incorrect syntax.

```
# read in netCDF file
f = nc4.Dataset(fn[0], 'r')

# read in group from file
sm_am = f.groups['Retrieval_Data_AM']

# extract variables
vwc = np.asarray(sm_am.variables['water_content'][:,:])
any_variable = np.asarray(sm_am.variables['generic_variables'][:,:])
```

Then I want to extract other variables only when vwc<5.

Comment: The `np.asarray()` isn't necessary here, `var=sm_am.variables['some_var'][:]` should be enough. Can you include the full code which gives you the errors, including the traceback of the errors? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If I don't add the `np.asarray()`, I get a `masked array`. What is a masked array and how is it different/advantageous than an unmasked array? I've run into issues with masked arrays before and so have then added the `np.asarray()` to all future code.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for filtering out my data.

```
x = vwc > 5.0 # Boolean condition
new_var = old_var.copy() # copying old data as new variable
new_var[x] = np.nan # replace elements that meet the condition with NaN
```

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution. One small remark: `new_var = old_var` doesn't actually _copy_ the data; if you change `new_var`, `old_var` will be changed as well (see https://pastebin.com/MCAzTJK4 for a small example). If you want a hard copy, use `new_var = old_var.copy()`.

Comment: I noticed that the `old_var` was getting changed as well. Thank you!! I'll fix it now in the answer.